# Typescript | Calling a Function via Reference Does Not Work

Tags: typescript

I am trying to call a function via reference. It all starts in `callMe()` of class `DynamicCalls`:

```js
interface IDynamicFunction {
    name: string;
    func: (param: string) => void;
}

class DynamicCalls {

    private dynamicCall: IDynamicFunction = { name: "myDynamic", func: this.testFunc };

    public callMe() {
        this.callFromDynamic("Works"); // 1st -> Works
        this.testFunc("Works, also"); // 2nd -> Works
        this.dynamicCall.func("First Call"); // 3rd -> Error: callFromDynamic seems to be unknown in testFunc
    }

    private callFromDynamic(param: string): void {
        console.log("Param: " + param);
    }

    private testFunc(param: string): void {
        console.log("Param: " + param);
        this.callFromDynamic("Second call"); // Gives error -> TypeError: this.callFromDynamic is not a function
    }
}

let dynamicCalls: DynamicCalls = new DynamicCalls();

dynamicCalls.callMe();
```

I expect that the 3rd call `(this.dynamicCall.func("First Call");)` works like `this.testFunc("Works, also")`.

Can anyone explain to me why I get this `TypeError: this.callFromDynamic is not a function`? And how I can avoid it?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Kind regards,
Okean

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you lose the context.

In your case, `this` refers to the same object: `{name: string, func: Function}`

So you could work with:

```js
private dynamicCall: IDynamicFunction = {
  name: "myDynamic",
  anotherFun: () => console.log('another func'),
  func: this.anotherFun()
};
```

Try:

```js
private dynamicCall: IDynamicFunction = {
  name: "myDynamic",
  func: (param: string) => this.testFunc(param)
};
```

Answer (score 0):

@MaximP is right, but there is another solution.

```js
    private callFromDynamic = (param: string): void => {
        console.log("Param: " + param);
    };

    private testFunc = (param: string): void => {
        console.log("Param: " + param);
        this.callFromDynamic("Second call");
    };
```

Change your functions to fields, now they'll keep their context without need to wrap their calls.